# What is the difference between serializability and linearizability?

Tags: distributed-computing

I am very confused between these two consistency models. Please give some timeline examples along with explanation. 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistency_model

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It was hard to find information about this subject. However, At some point I found a statement that explained it clearly:

- Linearizability gives isolation at the level of operations, while Serializability gives isolation at the level of transactions.

*(summarized from the in-depth description [found here](http://www.bailis.org/blog/linearizability-versus-serializability/))*

As an example:

[image]

Here, A, B and C are three different transactions running at the same time. r(varname) means that the current transaction is accessing the value inside varname, and w(varname) means that the current transaction is writing a certain value in varname.

Now, to create a linearized history of these events, we have to make sure that no two operations are happening at the same time. An operation that has started while another operation already started should appear behind the first operation.

In this case:

```
Log1: A.r(x), B.r(X), B.r(Y), A.w(X), C.r(Y)
```

To create a Serialized history of these events, one has to separate all the operations of the transactions A, B and C so there are no interleaved operations from other transactions.

From our example this could result in:

```
Log2: A.r(x), A.w(x), B.r(X), B.r(Y), C.r(Y)
```

Answer (score 1):

please have a look at this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=noUNH3jDLC0&t

Martin Kleppmann is the writer of Designing Data-Intense Applications which is a great book and I'd highly recommend it to someone interested about either serializability or linearizability.

Comment: Generally, links [should be accompanied by usage notes, a specific explanation of how the linked resource is applicable to the problem, or some sample code](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251605), or if possible all of the above.

Answer (score 1):

Assume you have an object that you can do operations on. Define `transaction` to be a group of operations you wish to perform on this object.

Let H be the following history of transaction invocations and responses performed on your object by processes A, B, and C.

```
H = {A.inv, B.inv, B.res, C.inv, C.res, A.res}
Process A transaction:     |---------------------------|
Process B transaction:           |-----|
Process C transaction:                     |-----|
```

You can visually see processes A, B, and C are executing concurrent transactions of operations on the object.

If you assume that each transaction 'takes effect' at some fixed point in it's execution, you can 'break' apart this concurrent execution into a sequential history. There are multiple possible combinations for this: You can move transaction B to occur before A, or after A. You can move transaction C to occur before A, or after A. You can also make B happen before C, or C happen before B.

```
Possible sequential histories: ABC or ACB or BAC or BCA or CAB or CBA
```

If at least one of these sequential histories is **valid** for the object being operated on, for example you don't end up popping two items from a queue you only put one item into, then that sequential history is a **serialization** of H, and H is said to be **serializable**.

Notice that in the original history H, while A and B were concurrent, and A and C were concurrent, B and C were **not** concurrent: transaction B finished strictly before transaction C started. Only in such a case, where a transaction finished before another one started, we can define an order on the history: B < C.

If one of the possible serializations we listed above is **valid** and also **preserves this order**, then we say that that serialization is a **strict serialization** of H, and H is **strictly serializable**.

```
Possible sequential histories that preserve the order: ABC, BAC, BCA
```

These are the **strict serializations** of H because in all of them B < C.

In the **special case** that all of the transactions (in this case A, B, and C) only have a single operation in them, then the strict serialization is called a **linearization**, and H is said to be **linearizable**. The reason we give this special case it's own name is because it has some special unique properties that general strict-serializability does not have:

```
1) Linearizations are local properties. If a history of operations on 
   object x is linearizable, and a history on object y is linearizable, 
   then a history containing operations on both x and y is linearizable. 
   This means we only need to determine linearizability on a per-object 
   basis, which makes the system modular.

2) Linearizability does not require blocking. No process needs to block 
   to achieve linearizability.
```

---

Notice that strict-serializability implies linearizability, but not the other way around.

Notice that it is always a requirement that the resulting sequential history is valid for the object being operated on.

Notice that for a given history H, there can be many possible serializations, strict serializations, or linearizations.

Notice that in this conversation we are only determining serializability/linearizability for a specific given history H. Proving that a specific history is or isn't serializable or linearizable is easy. Proving that **any** history H in some concurrent system on some object will always be serializable or linearizable is **substantially harder**.